# PHP why doesn't preg_match work?

Tags: php

Hello I have the following code:

```
$headerOcc = substr_count($text, "[Image][");

  if($headerOcc < '1'){
    $text = $text;
  }


  for ($i=0; $i < $headerOcc; $i++) {      
      preg_match('/[Image\]\[(.*)\]/', $text, $match);
      $headerTitle = ($match[1]);           
      print($headerTitle);     
  }
```

I also have the following variable:

```
$text = "Hello world [Image][61][Image][62]Hello world";
```

I want to find out if there is a part of the text that says [image][ID]. Obviously the ID will be replaced by a number and I want to get it.  How can I get $headerTitle to return that ID inside the curly brackets. It currently gives me this when I print it:

```
61]**
```

**[Image][62

Which is not what I want. I want it to return:

```
61

62
```

What am i doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: You are using curly braces `{}` in `$text` but looking for brackets `[]` in the pattern.

Comment: Thats my mistake not a real mistake sorry. Ill fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all()` and use `\d+` to get the digits:

```
preg_match_all('/\[Image\]\[(\d+)\]/', $text, $matches);
```

Alternately you could match on NOT `]`, so `([^\]]+)`.

Then just loop `$matches[1]` to echo etc...

```
foreach($matches[1] as $headerTitle) {
    print($headerTitle);
}
```

No need for the `substr_count()` or any of the other stuff.